# Need a query which return free hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "agenda" like this

| PERID | DAYNUM | START_HOUR | END_HOUR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 08:00 | 11:00 |
| 100 | 3 | 13:00 | 15:00 |
| 100 | 3 | 16:00 | 18:00 |

And I need, with a select, to get the "free" hours of the agenda like this:

| START_H | END_H |
| --- | --- |
| 11:00 | 13:00 |
| 15:00 | 16:00 |

Do you have an idea on how to write the select to get this result?

Already thank you to be interested on my query.

Comment: Which's your DBMS: Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: I usually work with Oracle but here it's for Mysql.

Comment: This depends a bit on what assumptions about the data we can make, but I suspect you will have to start by joining `agenda` onto itself to take `END_HOUR` of the previous row as `START_HOUR` and `START_HOUR` of the current row as `END_HOUR` to get the possible free intervals, then check that `START_HOUR` < `END_HOUR`.

Comment: WITH MYSQL (8 yu could use LAG to determine if the previous row is idemtical to starttiome. but to save these data without a date, you will get imto trouble with midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEAD` and `CASE-WHEN` should do the trick:

```
select distinct START_H, end_h
from
(
select perid, daynum, start_hour, end_hour, 
    case 
      when (LEAD(start_hour) OVER(order by perid, daynum, start_hour, end_hour)) > end_hour then end_hour
      else NULL
    end as START_H,
    case 
      when (LEAD(start_hour) OVER(order by perid, daynum, start_hour, end_hour)) > end_hour then (LEAD(start_hour) OVER(order by perid, daynum, start_hour, end_hour))
      else NULL
    end as END_H
from agenda
)as sq
WHERE start_h IS NOT NULL 
   and end_h IS NOT NULL
```

**Note:** This will work perfectly for the sample data you provided. In case of date change or anything, you may have to update accordingly

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c7142f970c323594b5beadeab0da8ee)

Comment: A very big thank you for your help and clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: You can you use lag function with partition by to simplify the problem and then use timediff to get the end result.

```
select PREV_END_HOUR as START_H, START_HOUR as END_H
from (
    select *, 
lag(END_HOUR) over(partition by PERID, DAYNUM order by START_HOUR) as PREV_END_HOUR
    from 
    agenda) x
where timediff(START_HOUR,PREV_END_HOUR) > 0
```

The inner query will return the below result.

```
+-------+--------+------------+----------+---------------+
| PERID | DAYNUM | START_HOUR | END_HOUR | PREV_END_HOUR |
+-------+--------+------------+----------+---------------+
|   100 |      3 | 08:00:00   | 11:00:00 | NULL          |
|   100 |      3 | 13:00:00   | 15:00:00 | 11:00:00      |
|   100 |      3 | 16:00:00   | 18:00:00 | 15:00:00      |
+-------+--------+------------+----------+---------------+
```

The inner query partitions by the PERID, DAYNUM to ensure we are not comparing different period or different day. We then order by START_HOUR to ensure the order of classes is preserved for running the lag function in the correct order. We then run lag function and pass it the END_HOUR. This brings the previous class END_HOUR on the same row as the next START_HOUR which make its possible to compare the times.

Now that we have the previous class end hour on the same row we can add a outer query which checks if START_HOUR is greater than the PREV_END_HOUR. The final result is as below.

```
+----------+----------+
| START_H  | END_H    |
+----------+----------+
| 11:00:00 | 13:00:00 |
| 15:00:00 | 16:00:00 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you vey much to all for your help! Very appreciate!